# Return Folder name from string formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a xl file 'File Finder' that finds all files in the folder and sub folders and populates a table. In one of the columns, it puts the full path for each file found. What i need to do is get the folder name that is 2 sublevels from the File Finder. For example from the picture, there are two paths. I already know the File Finder path using `=LEFT(CELL("filename"),FIND("[",CELL("filename"))-1)` which returns ...\On Portable, but i cant return the 2nd sub folder name into the cell. So what i would like to return is 'Activities Department Docs' or 'Care Department Docs' or so on. Thanks

[image]

Comment: See if something along the lines of `=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()-1]")` works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Little hard to tell what you want from your example, or what the possible variations might be, but one way to return the second to last slash separated substring, if you do not have the `FILTERXML` function, is:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",999)),IF(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))))-1)*999),999)),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","")))
```

There are shorter formulas depending on your Excel version. And this one is easily modified to return the `nth` from end item

[image]

The formula

- creates an array where each slash-separated string as an element
- uses the index function to return the desired element.